# How to position a node at the center of the screen in spritekit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In spritekit, is there a quick way to position a node at the center of the screen without having to calculate the coordinate manually?

Answer (score 6):

Apart from Ron Myschuk answer you can also use the scene frame property. I think this way is the most flexible as it will work regardless of anchor point.

e.g

```
// Center
yourNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY) 

// Slightly off centre
yourNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX - 100, y: frame.midY - 100)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

if your scene has an anchorPoint of `CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)` then any object you add to the scene will automatically be placed in the center of the screen.

If your scene has an anchorPoint of CPoint.zero (lower left corner) you can set the position of the object by setting `object.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height/ 2)` where self is the scene

Comment: This causes a "Found nil while implicitly unwrapping optional" error

Comment: @ParsaNoori no it doesn't . If your object is nil and you try to set a property of it it'll generate a nil error, but that is irrelevant to this answer or question

Comment: You're right. Sadly the object I was assigning to it caused the error.